# Cohomology of restrictions of the universal bundle over a surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective, algebraic surface and $H$ be an ample divisor on $X$. Let $ M_H : = M_{X,H}(r;c_1,c_2)$ be the moduli space of rank $r$, $H$-stable vector bundles  on $X$ with fixed Chern invariants $c_1,c_2$. Assume that $ M_H$ is a fine moduli space and $U$ be the universal bundle.

Then can we say that there exists an effective divisor $D$ on $X$ such that for every $p \in M_H$, $H^i(U|_{X \times \{p\}} \otimes D)=0$ for $i >0$?

In my situation there are more cohomological conditions on the members of $M_H$ but I guess that has nothing to do with existence of such a $D$.

Any suggestion regarding the existence of $D$ which is independent of $p$ is appreciated

Comment: This is just semi-continuity and much more general.

Comment: @Mohan, if at least one such element satisfies the cohomology vanishing condition, then by semicontinuity a general member of an irreducible component (containing the elememt of the previous line) of the moduli space will satisfy the cohomology vanishing condition. But the moduli space in consideration may not be irreducible. Could you please briefly indicate the correct application of semicontinuity and the general version?